# How to make nightwatch.js test more DRY

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm learning nightwatch.js and am finding a lot of repeated code.  For example,

```
// works

    objects.expect.element('@user').to.be.present

    objects.expect.element('@user').value.to.match(/\S/)

    objects.expect.element('@user').value.to.not.equal(username)
```

Where `objects.expect.element('@user')` is obviously repeated.  In this case, if I don't repeat that for each line, then I end up failing.

For example, if instead I use

```
// fails

    objects.expect.element('@user').to.be.present

                                   .value.to.match(/\S/)

                                   .value.to.not.equal(username)
```

results in a fail message starting with, `Expected element <#who> to be present not equal: "Ned the Nighthawk" not match: "/\S/"  - expected "not present" but got: present`

Is there a way to make this code more DRY?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately nightwatch's `expect` namespace doesn't offer chaining.
In order to chain your assertions you need to use classic `assert`/`verify` library.

http://nightwatchjs.org/api#assertions